# Effortless Ctags in Vim

Tags: git, vim, githooks, ctags

I followed Tim Pope's blog post on [effortless ctags with git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) however it doesn't seem to work.

The output of `git ctags`

```
fatal: cannot exec '.git/hooks/ctags': Permission denied
```

I have followed the instructions as he as explained. 
My `~/.git_template/hooks` folder has the following files.

```
ctags  post-checkout  post-commit post-merge post-rewrite
```

I have tried reinitializing a repository and committing but neither seems to generate the ctags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you missed a:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/ctags
```

On the script, which you need to set the [executable bit](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/ExecutableBit).